# How to know which index in the class is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, button

Looking at this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_getelementsbyclassname) , I was thinking classes are actually indexed. If I have this code, how can I get in JavaScript or jQuery the index of the class of the button clicked?

```
<button class="class_name" id="b1"></button>
<button class="class_name" id="b2"></button>
```

Comment: Somewhat confusing, classes aren't indexed, and there isn't really an indexing going on at all, but jQuery has an `index` method that will count the number of siblings above an element and tell you how many other elements there are before it in the DOM, giving you a sort of index ?

Comment: They are seemed to be indexed in this example of w3schools. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_getelementsbyclassname

Comment: That's much clearer than the initial question. Any method that has an `s` indicating plural, such as `getElements ...` returns a [nodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), which is an array-like object with indices to access each element that is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/mg7zau4c/

jQuery [index](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

> Search for a given element from among the matched elements.

```
$('.class_name').on('click', function(){
    console.log($(this).index());
});
```

> Thanks. How to return the id from this? –  Syntactic 7 mins ago

```
$(this).attr('id');
```

Comment: Thanks. How to return the id from this?

Comment: `$(this).attr('id');`

Answer (score 0):

in jquery:
    $( "#b1" ).index()

EDIT: just saw your update, you could do this in jquery to button clicked index

```
$('button').click(function (event) {
    alert($(this).index());
});
```

Comment: How to return the id as I am going to set it as a variable

Comment: `$(this).attr('id');`

Answer (score 0):

You may be thinking of a `NodeList` which is returned by `var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.class_name')`  which can then do `nodes.length` and `console(nodes[1].id)` for instance.

[see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery:

```
var index, 
    buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('class_name');
for(var i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
    buttons[i].onclick = function(){
        for(var j=0;<buttons.length;j++){
             if(buttons[j]==this) {
                 index = j; //console.log(j), etc
                 break;
             }
        }
    }
}
```

With one less curly bracket, and a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fq4Lng2n/):

```
[].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('class_name')).forEach(function(o,i,arr){
    o.onclick = function(){
       var index, that = this;
       var search = arr.some(function(b,j){
           index = j;
           return that == b;
       });
       alert(index);
   }
});
```

NodeLists are always in order, but if you reorder the elements you will have to query `getElementsByClassName` again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to iterate through the children an element containing the buttons. Assuming the only children are the buttons in question, you can get the index like this.

```js
document.getElementById('buttonContainer').addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
  var clickedButton = e.target, 
      index = -1; 
  [].slice.call(this.children).some(function(el, idx) { 
    if (e.target === el) { 
      index = idx; 
      return true; 
    }
    return false; 
  }); 
  document.getElementById('indexText').textContent = index + ' ' + e.target.id; 
});
```

```html
<div id="buttonContainer">
<button class="class_name" id="red"></button>
<button class="class_name" id="blue"></button>
<button class="class_name" id="purple"></button>
<button class="class_name" id="magenta"></button>
<button class="class_name" id="rouge"></button>
<button class="class_name" id="cyan"></button>
<button class="class_name" id="yellow"></button>
<button class="class_name" id="black"></button>
  </div>
<p id="indexText"></p>
```